# Apache application in subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, webserver, virtualhost, apache-directory

I put my application in a subfolder "subfolder" of Apache so I can use a url such as: https://myserver.com/subfolder/#/v2/login instead of https://myserver.com/#/v2/login

I'm using the following Directory configuration:

```
Alias /subfolder /srv/apache2/htdocs/subfolder
<Directory /srv/apache2/htdocs/subfolder>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

The problem is that now I have many broken links and not found resources showing errors such as:

```
https://myserver.com/app/v2/anotherfolder/anotherpage.html 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Note that such links in the errors do not contain "subfolder" in the path.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your site root .htaccess (i.e. `htdocs/`) use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?!subfolder/).* subfolder/$0 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to enter this below in your .htaccess file in your public directory in your "subfolder" directory. I assume that you already did the changed that you must have done in your virtual hosts file.

```
RewriteBase /subfolder (just below RewriteEngine On)
```